# Manual Pagination Error - Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I am getting the following error while passing an array, `count(array)` and `itemsPerPage` as arguments. 
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::make()`

I tried following with it but cant fix the error.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Factory;
use App\Response;
```

`make` method is defined in http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Pagination/Environment.html#method_make document.

Comment: More code please... cmon if you want help post everything **relevant** you've got so people don't need to ask for it.

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward - you're trying to use a method that doesn't exist. Try passing the same data to the constructor of `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` (or `LengthAwarePaginator`, depending on your needs) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try to remove these lines:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator;
```

Then add this:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

Then use `$paginator->render()` instead of `make()`

Answer (score 0):

Remove those two:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination;
```

That's all.